# SQLAlchemy map to list related objects

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a problem with mapping relation between two entities in SQLAlchemy. I am trying to achieve the next behaviour -> map to User all related Feedbacks. The relation is by `receiver_id` on the other side, which is equal to `user_id`. So, User 1 is sending a feedback for User 2 and I am trying to get them as a list when I get User 2 object. I have next code

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    user_id = sa.Column('user_id', UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    first_name = sa.Column('first_name', sa.String)
    last_name = sa.Column('last_name', sa.String)
    phone_number = sa.Column('phone_number', sa.String(20), unique=True)
    email = sa.Column('email', sa.String, unique=True)
    is_active = sa.Column('is_active', sa.Boolean, server_default=expression.true(), nullable=False)
    deleted = sa.Column('deleted', sa.Boolean, server_default=expression.false(), nullable=False)
    created_time = sa.Column('created_time', sa.DateTime, server_default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    updated_time = sa.Column('updated_time', sa.DateTime, server_default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    deleted_time = sa.Column('deleted_time', sa.DateTime)
    feedbacks = relationship('UserFeedback', primaryjoin='User.user_id == UserFeedback.receiver_id', uselist=True, lazy='dynamic', backref='user_feedback')


class UserFeedback(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_feedback"
    id = sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    sender_id = sa.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False)
    receiver_id = sa.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False)

    sender = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[sender_id])
    receiver = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[receiver_id])

    rating = sa.Column('rating', sa.DECIMAL, nullable=False)
    feedback = sa.Column('feedback', sa.String, nullable=False)
    date = sa.Column('date', sa.DateTime, server_default=func.now(), nullable=False)
```

I've filled the database with user feedbacks but when I pull user ORM doesn't map related feedbacks. It actually doesn't even have this field, so that's a little confusing

I am learning SQLAlchemy, so would appreciate help or recommendation on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you're using `dynamic` loading strategy for relationship ([the docs are here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders)).

When querying with `lazy = 'dynamic'`, SQLAlchemy generates a separate query rather than fetching actual results. So in your initial case `feedbacks` attribute contains another `select` statement (of `AppenderQuery` type) you can execute manually.

To simply get the related data just change 'dynamic' to 'joined'.

You can read more about relationship loading strategies in [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html) or in [this beautiful post](https://medium.com/@ns2586/sqlalchemys-relationship-and-lazy-parameter-4a553257d9ef).